# What is considered as whitespace in HTTP header

Tags: http, whitespace, standards

I've just been reading HTTP standard (*propsed standard* to be more precise) part 1 and got confused with what they consider as "whitespace" in section 3, second to last paragraph:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3

Since returns (CRLFs) terminate HTTP header, the only whitespaces that may be implied are `0x20` 'Space' characters. Wikipedia lists another kinds of whitespace ASCII symbols, like 'Non-breaking space' `0xA0`, so I still don't understand this ("whitespace") concept.

Please, help me figure out what it really means in scope of this standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RFC 7230, which you linked to, defines EXACTLY what it considers to be whitespace in a header:

```
HTTP-message   = start-line
                 *( header-field CRLF )
                 CRLF
                 [ message-body ]

header-field   = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS

field-name     = token
field-value    = *( field-content / obs-fold )
field-content  = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]
field-vchar    = VCHAR / obs-text

obs-fold       = CRLF 1*( SP / HTAB )
               ; obsolete line folding
               ; see Section 3.2.4

obs-text       = %x80-FF

OWS            = *( SP / HTAB )
               ; optional whitespace
```

As you can see, `SP` (space) and `HTAB` (horizontal tab) are the only defined whitespace characters.  They are defined in [RFC 5234 Appendix B.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#appendix-B.1), which RFC 7230 links to:

```
HTAB           =  %x09
               ; horizontal tab

SP             =  %x20
```

Comment: I was searching this for Delphi only and seeing a Delphi Maestro's answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. See also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.3.
2. HTAB is also whitespace.
3. In the context of Section 3, "A sender MUST NOT send whitespace between the start-line and the first header field." also refers to extra line breaks.

Comment: Are you sure about the third? I mean, extra line breaks would be interpreted as header termination.

Comment: Yes, that's why you MUST NOT send them.

Comment: @JulianReschke if i am reading the spec correctly, it appears that the optional white space can be 0 or more spaces or htabs, correct? I ask as i would like to implement a simple server in an embedded device with limited memory and would like to be able to left pad the content-length field with spaces to avoid having to recompute the entire header each time.

Comment: Yes. But remember; SHLULD NOT generate.