# Should a space character in an http header use %20 or +

Tags: http, https

I've searched here and google and been unable to find an answer to my question.
In an http header, should a space be encoded as a %20 or a + or is either acceptable ?

Specifically in my case the S3 Request Header `x-amz-copy-source` which is described as "The source bucket name + object name.  {bucket}/{obj}".

I'm testing some code with two S3 providers (Amazon & Dreamhost). Amazon expect a + and Dreamhost a %20.

I'm trying to find out if both are correct (and thus my code needs to cope appropriately) or whether one of them goes against a standard (and thus there's a chance it they will change in the future) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP header fields can contain space characters; there's no requirement to escape them (unless they appear at the beginning or end).

What if any kind of escaping is used thus depends on the definition of the actual HTTP header field (not HTTP in general).

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting and testing it seems that if I just leave the space unencoded it does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179659/what-is-considered-as-whitespace-in-http-header#:%7E:text=Since%20returns%20(CRLFs)%20terminate%20HTTP,are%200x20%20%27Space%27%20characters.), it seems that only Dreamhost is compliant to the RFC.

Comment: Thanks. I had read that and the RFC but I couldn't see anything that said you couldn't use +, but then I'm not au fait with the way RFC's are worded.